# How to use recursion to parse groups inside groups in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

I'm just starting with recursion, so if someone can try to help I will very much appreciate it.

I have the following `String`:

```
field1: typeA
field2: typeA
field3: typeB
group1:
    fieldA: typeA
    fieldB: typeB
    subGroup1:
        fieldX: typeB
        fieldY: typeB
    fieldC: typeC
field4: typeA
group2:
    fieldA: typeB
    subGroup1:
        fieldX: typeA
        fieldY: typeA
    fieldB: typeA
    fieldC: typeC
field5: typeC
field6: typeD
```

Note that I can have groups inside groups (subgroups). I can also have groups inside groups inside groups, so recursion is mandatory as far as I know.

Note that the *spacing* in the beginning of each line determines if the field belongs to the group or not.

I would like to write a method in Java that will return a `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>`, where the *Object* map value can either be a `String` denoting that this is a field (not a group) or another `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>` denoting that this is a group (not a field).

I've tried but failed miserably. Recursion is just too hard for me at the moment, but I'm studying it.

To help whoever wants to help, below the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String text = String.join("\n",
                
                "field1: typeA",
                "field2: typeA",
                "field3: typeB",
                "group1:",
                "    fieldA: typeA",
                "    fieldB: typeB",
                "    subGroup1:",
                "        fieldX: typeB",
                "        fieldY: typeB",
                "    fieldC: typeC",
                "field4: typeA",
                "group2:",
                "    fieldA: typeB",
                "    subGroup1:",
                "        fieldX: typeA",
                "        fieldY: typeA",
                "    fieldB: typeA",
                "    fieldC: typeC",
                "field5: typeC",
                "field6: typeD",
                
                "");
        
        Map<String, Object> solution = doIt(text);
        System.out.println(solution);
    }
    
    private static LinkedHashMap<String, Object> doIt(String text) {
        // solution goes here...
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the correct output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    
    map.put("field1", "typeA");
    map.put("field2", "typeA");
    map.put("field3", "typeB");
    
    Map<String, Object> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    map2.put("fieldA", "typeA");
    map2.put("fieldB", "typeB");
    
    Map<String, Object> map3 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    map3.put("fieldX", "typeB");
    map3.put("fieldY", "typeB");
    map2.put("subGroup1", map3);
    
    map2.put("fieldC", "typeC");
    
    map.put("group1", map2);
    
    map.put("field4", "typeA");
    
    Map<String, Object> map4 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    map4.put("fieldA", "typeB");
    
    Map<String, Object> map5 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    map5.put("fieldX", "typeA");
    map5.put("fieldY", "typeA");
    map4.put("subGroup1", map5);
    
    map4.put("fieldB", "typeA");
    map4.put("fieldC", "typeC");
    
    map.put("group2", map4);
    
    map.put("field5", "typeC");
    map.put("field6", "typeD");
    
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

With the output:

```
{field1=typeA, field2=typeA, field3=typeB, group1={fieldA=typeA, fieldB=typeB, subGroup1={fieldX=typeB, fieldY=typeB}, fieldC=typeC}, field4=typeA, group2={fieldA=typeB, subGroup1={fieldX=typeA, fieldY=typeA}, fieldB=typeA, fieldC=typeC}, field5=typeC, field6=typeD}
```

Comment: This looks a YAML document. If you use a YAML parser like SnakeYAML ([tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml)) you could potentially recurse through the returned object, converting it into your desired format.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I would like to learn how to actually do it, instead of using an external parser that will do everything for me without teaching me recursion.

Comment: Add your miserable failure (:-)), so we can see where you need help.

Comment: I added the desired map, done by hand. I'm afraid I don't have anything useful to post. I did not make much progress, brain went into a dadelock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a `Queue` to hold the lines of your text. The queue is consumed by your function, recursing each time it detects a new group. The use of a queue allows you to `peek` at each line, so when you find the end of the current group, by checking for the level of indentation, you can return and let the previous call handle the remaining fields.

```
static String INDENT = "    ";

static LinkedHashMap<String, Object> doIt(Queue<String> q, String ind) 
{
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
    while(!q.isEmpty())
    {
        String line = q.peek();
        
        if(!line.startsWith(ind)) break;
        
        q.poll();
        
        int idx = line.indexOf(":");
        String name = line.substring(ind.length(), idx);
        String value = line.substring(idx+1).trim();
        
        if(!value.isEmpty())
            map.put(name, value);
        else
            map.put(name, doIt(q, ind + INDENT));
    }
    
    return map;
}
```

Test:

```
String text = String.join("\n",
  
  "field1: typeA",
  "field2: typeA",
  "field3: typeB",
  "group1:",
  "    fieldA: typeA",
  "    fieldB: typeB",
  "    subGroup1:",
  "        fieldX: typeB",
  "        fieldY: typeB",
  "    fieldC: typeC",
  "field4: typeA",
  "group2:",
  "    fieldA: typeB",
  "    subGroup1:",
  "        fieldX: typeA",
  "        fieldY: typeA",
  "    fieldB: typeA",
  "    fieldC: typeC",
  "field5: typeC",
  "field6: typeD",
  
  "");

Map<String, Object> solution = doIt(new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(text.split("\n"))), "");
print(solution, "");
```

Where the`print` method looks like this (note we have to suppress warnings due to the unsafe cast):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static void print(Map<String, Object> map, String ind)
{
    for(String name : map.keySet())
    {
        Object value = map.get(name);
        if(value instanceof String)
            System.out.println(ind + name + ": " + value);
        else
        {
            System.out.println(ind + name + ":");
            print((Map<String, Object>)value, ind + INDENT);
        }           
    }
}
```

Output:

```
field1: typeA
field2: typeA
field3: typeB
group1:
    fieldA: typeA
    fieldB: typeB
    subGroup1:
        fieldX: typeB
        fieldY: typeB
    fieldC: typeC
field4: typeA
group2:
    fieldA: typeB
    subGroup1:
        fieldX: typeA
        fieldY: typeA
    fieldB: typeA
    fieldC: typeC
field5: typeC
field6: typeD
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! O.o O.o O.o. How do you get so good with recursion?